# Can't get two 4k ultrawide displays to work on PC

Tags: pc, hdmi, cable

I'm trying to connect two 4k ultrawide monitors to my PC for multi-display extended desktop setup, but I can't get the other monitor to work. My mobo has 1x DVI-D 1x D-Sub and 1x HDMI outputs.
Both displays only have DP / HDMI ports and I have no idea what do I need to hook the other one up.

I've tried a 24-pin DVI-D to HDMI cable but that only gets it to work for a second then shows static, and from what I found that's related to the cable not supporting above 1080p resolutions.

What sort of cable would I need to hook it to the PC?

Comment: Or this is tech support and you should ask this on Super User, or you are asking for some piece of hardware and it's not clear to me what you are asking (although that could be a me problem since I got out of bed 5 minutes ago)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [DVI to HDMI adapter](https://a.co/d/iiXBrC1). DVI only supports 2k, not 4k, so you will not get the full resolution. There is no cable that will fix this for you. **Your computer is capable of running two displays, just not two 4k displays.**

Your [LG 34WK95U-W](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34WK95U-W-ultrawide-monitor) monitor is WUHD (5120 x 2160), which is even higher than 4k. DVI-D and Dsub are not capable of driving your displays at full resolution. Even the HDMI port will only work if it is at least HDMI 2.0 and you will not get the full color and refresh rate unless it is HDMI 2.1.

Those monitors are also capable of being driven by Thunderbolt 3, but as your are using an AMD system, you would need a [Thunderbolt 3 PCIe card](https://smile.amazon.com/FebSmart-10-15-x-Build-Self-Powered-Technology-FS-C2-Pro/dp/B089YN57TD), which will give your the proper connecting ports, but does not guarantee that your computer will be able to drive both displays.

Your best course of action is to install a dedicated GPU. I recommend the [6500 XT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09PSHYHLM). It has DiplayPort 1.4a and HDMI 2.1. It's one of the cheaper cards right now that is capable of what you need and one of the very best price-to-performance cards at the moment.

Comment: I have LG 34WK95U-W monitor and a Ryzen 7 PRO 4750 g with vega 8 graphics, no dedicated gpu. Specs said that it should be able to run dual monitor setup

Comment: That adapter and the cable they tried are essentially the same thing and both are only going to support single-link DVI which has even lower resolution support than DVI-D. Basically only good for 1080p at 60hz and not much better.

Comment: The link I provided is DVI-D, not single-link DVI. DVI-D is capable of 2560×1600 at 60Hz or 1920×1080 at 144Hz. That's as good as the computer described can do.

Comment: The adapter you posted is "DVI-D", and D stands for digital. Sorry I made an error in my comment and meant to say "lower res. support than dual link". Those passive ones are only single-link though and the extra pins aren't even used by the HDMI side. It will have a max resolution of 1920x1200. There are active adapters that actually convert from DVI-D dual link to a newer HDMI standard and support 2560x1440 like you're saying.

Comment: I didn't realize that required an active adapter. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: For anyone following these comments, those active DVI DualLink adapters cost >$90. Don't do it.